# How to fix: Error: couldn't connect to server <ip address>:27017, connection attempt failed: Connection refused

Tags: mongodb

I'm running mongodb on a remote server and I want to access within my local machine

I've tried to remove the mongodb.lock file, also tried `sudo mongod --repair` but none of these worked for me.

This happens when I'm doing `mongo <ip address>:27017/testDB` or simply `mongo <ip address>`

I'm getting:

```
[js] Error: couldn't connect to server <ip address>:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <ip address>:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

The mongo.cfg file looks like this:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


#processManagement:

#security:
  authorization: 'enabled'

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: maybe the issue is with the CORS.. since the connection is refused.. maybe cross origin (remote connection) is not available. You have to give white-list remote IP most probably..

Comment: 'Connection refused' has exactlly one meaning. Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. Either the server wasn't started or the IP:port isn't correct.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal CORS within the local machine? Really?

Comment: @user207421 i have verified both of it, still getting the error

Comment: @user207421 he is running DB on a remote machine... and accessing it from a local machine... cross origin.. request origin IP is not same as DB IP...

Comment: @HimanshuBansal how can get the white-list IP, i don't know anything about that.

Comment: @emeric Check answer and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 8):

Open up mongodb config file:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

Window:

```
MongoDB_installation_Directory/Server/{version}/bin/mongod.cfg 
// MongoDB_installation_Directory could be C://MongoDB or C://Program Files/MongoDB
```

Edit:

```
# network interfaces
net:
    port: 27017
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0   #default value is 127.0.0.1
```

Restart MongoDB Server:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

By default mongodb is configured to allow connections only from localhost. We need to allow remote connections. In the config file, go to the network interfaces section and change the bindIp from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` **which means allow connections from all IP addresses**.

***You can also enable MongoDB Auth:***

Open up mongo shell:

```
mongo
```

Inside mongo shell access the admin database. Create a new admin user.

```
> use admin;
> db.createUser({
      user: "admin",
      pwd: "password",
      roles: [
                { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase",   db: "admin" }
             ]
  });
```

Now create db users and grant them roles on their respective databases.

```
> db.createUser({
      user: "user",
      pwd: "user_password",
      roles: [
                { role: "userAdmin", db: "yourDB" },
                { role: "dbAdmin",   db: "yourDB" },
                { role: "readWrite", db: "yourDB" }
             ]
  });
```

In the same config file,

```
security:
    authorization: 'enabled'
```

restart MongoDB:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Windows:

```
"MongoDB_installation_Directory/Server/{version}/bin/mongod.exe" --dbpath path/to/db
// MongoDB_installation_Directory could be C://MongoDB or C://Program Files/MongoDB
```

To Access mongo using auth on remote:

```
# to access the admin database
mongo -u admin -p password {public IP}/admin

# to access the other databases
mongo -u user -p user_password {public IP}/yourDB
```

Comment: i'm having an issue because the remote server run under windows, commands such as "sudo", "service" are not recognized by the command line tool.

Comment: @emeric updated answer for windows file system, except for location rest all is same :)

Comment: @emeric no problem :) if it resolve your issue do accept so others can get help from it as well ^^

Comment: now i'm facing another error: "Error: Authentication failed."

Comment: @emeric can you share the auth configs?

Comment: i added the mongo.cfg file , check it up

Comment: @emeric disable authorization once and try again...and for the connection problem.. i think that's resolved..

Comment: when i'm using the "127.0.0.1" to connect to mongodb i'm having "Error: Authenctication failed". And when i'm using the ip address i'm having "[js] Error: couldn't connect to server 208.67.222.222:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 192.168.26.1:27017 :: caused by :: Operation timed out :"

Comment: we use 127.0.0.1 when we are on the same system as of DB.. we use IP to connect to remote DB...What's the public IP of the DB??

Comment: can you check your server logs to detect that your are receiving any requests or not? I just tried the same configs over remote DB to check and it was working..

Comment: I checked the server logs i'm not receiving any request from my local machine. Have you done any config on the local machine?

Comment: @emeric none.. just simple mongo to connect to remote server .... since you are not receiving any requests on remote server... check the IP that you are using is correct and if Your server is receiving any requests other than DB.... Check if any proxy servers are not blocking/rejecting the requests... Can't debug much with less information... What are the setting you have done over the servers.. for PORTS/Requests/Logs/Proxy Servers?? Try to keep confidential information hidden..

Comment: after updating mongod.conf and mongod restart I am able to connect.

Comment: This is a great guide for setting up a remote instance. Cheers!

Comment: I am getting same error when I try to connect my one of the mongodb shards from another machine. I am running mongodb instances with a docker compose environment. There is no file named mongod.conf in etc/. There is a file named mongod.conf.orig. Should I edit it to add my other machines IP address ?

Comment: @BerdinEgeTurgut Hi, sorry for replying a bit late. When you install the docker image, it does most of the mappings so you don't have to do any changes to the `conf` file. This could be an issue related to `.yml` file configurations. Please check the environment variables and port. Can't help much without understanding the structure or configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @himanshu-bansal I had this problem and solved it by:

1. opening mongo.conf (as @himanshu-bansal said)

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

2. and, then adding the IP of my server:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 37.151.180.40,127.0.0.1 #for mongo 4
```

3. and then restarting mongo.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

I hope it works for you too.
One more thing, I preferred to bind two IPs because I wanted to keep my localhost.

Now by my `cmd` or `mongo compass`, I can connect to my mongo server with the IP `37.151.180.40`.

```
mongo 37.151.180.40:27017
```

I hope it will help you and, please read the details @himanshu-bansal said in answers.